# Dry hopping fruit beer

Tags: fruit, dry-hop

I am making a batch of apricot honey ale. i just added my appricots on secondary and want to dry hop later.

Do I need to rack the beer to tertiary before dry hopping or just throw in the hops once the second fermentation of the fruit stops?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some brewers and commentators say not to dry hop during active fermentation as the release of CO2 from the fermenting vessel may take some of the hop aroma and flavour. IMHO that is not particularly noticeable on the final product and so I dry hop at anytime during the brew process - most noticeably from day 4 until (say) day 14. IMHO there is no need to rack the beer into a third brew bin to dry hop it. It would be just as easy and effective to do it in the secondary bin.

Comment: I'd say, it's not release of CO2 which is the problem, but absorption of hop aromatics by yeast (as yeast are just small bags with stuff inside). On homebrew scale it doesn't matter much, because a homebrewer can just add more hops; in a commercial setup I'd rather remove yeast first, to save on hops. Which brings me to the main point: I'd say it's OK to dry hop without racking into tertiary IF the op finds a way to remove fruits first. Otherwise I'm afraid a big share of hop aromatics will be absorbed by fruits.

Comment: @Roman how significant though, because in the end I can just throw in more hops ( was going with about 100 grams for 28 liters)

Comment: @LucasKauffman I can't really say, but 100g hops should be quite enough